# design table database, duplicated register or create another table?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I want you to know your opnion about this situation:
I have a table named "movie" with this colums

- movie_id
- name
- price
  ...... etc

A movie can be available to rent, purchased or both.
If I want a movie available to rent and purchase the price change, for example:

Price for rent: $2.50

Price for purchase: $15.45

The question is:

Is better to make a duplicate in the table movie?

```
movie_id     name     price     available_for  ......    ........
    1        300      $2.50         rent
    2        300      $15.45        purchase
```

Or make another table adding the info of price and available_for? Like this:

Table Movie

```
movie_id     name   ......     ..........     ..........
    1        300
    2        300
```

Table Movie_available_for

```
Id     movie_id     available_for    price
 1         1           rent           $2.50
 2         1           purchase       $15.45
```

I want to know which is the best solution for this
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relational approach might depend on what level of normalization you hope to achieve.  Your question reminds me a lot of the Boyce–Codd normal form (BCNF) vs the 3rd normal form (3NF).

In fact, there is an example similar to your question on this wiki page: [Boyce–Codd normal form (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form)

There is a lot of theory here, but it can many times come down to either what you feel the most comfortable with or whichever technique you can perform the most accurately.

Personally, in this specific case, I would go with the slightly more normalized form (your 2nd example).  This is because, the "available_for" and "price" are related variables.  If you end up adding more info about movies, that info is potentially going to be duplicated many times.  If you add a third "availible_for" or different pricing schemes (1 day for $1.50, 5 days for $4), you will have very significant data duplication.

Besides, when it comes to code, it would be nice to have a movie object that has an array of nested "availible_for" (might name this something else like "offering" or something) objects.

Comment: I'm agree with you about the duplicates of addtional data, because if the user that add the movie's info wants to edit some info he have to edit it twice (if the solutionis the first one (duplicates) ).

Comment: Duplicates are generally bad indeed.  Most of the time it seems like there won't be too much duplication, but as tables grow and columns are added, duplication will grow.  I usually normalize to the point of using lookup tables.

Comment: In the SQL side, is better make JOINS or SELECT the duplicated info?

Comment: What do you mean by JOIN or SELECT duplicated data?

Comment: If I'm going to get the movie info in the "duplicate solution" I just do  SELECT * FROM movies, but with the other solution I have to do SELECT * FROM movie m JOIN Movie_available_for maf ON (m.movie_id=maf.movie_id)  wich is the best performance?

Comment: With shallow joins, the performance is many times going to be negligible.  Your SQL story is going to depend on what you do in your code.  If you are using a heavy ORM, then design your database how they recommend.  If you are doing raw SQL calls or using a "micro ORM", then you might have a little more freedom.

Comment: If you are really worried about performance, use views and stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you normalize your **available_for** column as it is repeated and contains few fields only.Store that in another table and create a relation between two tables.

Movie_Available_type

id int, available_for varchar(50)

Then you can use either of two as pointed out by thoughtarray in above post.

Comment: Introducing a surrogate key isn't normalizing.  Surrogate keys are better identifiers in many cases (and overused in many others), but they don't affect the normal form of a relation at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
Movie (movie_id PK, name, purchase_price, rent_price)
```

and make the pricing columns nullable.  If you don't like nulls, you can decompose it into:

```
Movie (movie_id PK, name)
PurchasePrice (movie_id PK/FK, price)
RentPrice (movie_id PK/FK, price)
```